# Convert integer to space separated list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist, input

I have the input as:

The first line contains two space separated integers N and M. Then in the next line are the NxM inputs of the matrix A:
Input:

```
4 5
11110
11010
11000
00000
```

I want the output as a list of list (integer)

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In competitive coding the inputs are taken as shown below:

**Try:**

```
n,m = map(int, input().split())

mat = []
for i in range(n):
    row = list(map(int,list(input())))
    mat.append(row)

print(mat)
```

**mat:**

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

You can test it via [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/Lmx6jAIoza)

Answer (score 0):

Read the inputs as string. then you can use this snippet to get the output

```
op_list = []
def to_list(number):
    return [int(dig) for dig in number]

op_list.append(to_list("11110"))
op_list.append(to_list("11010"))
op_list.append(to_list("11000"))
op_list.append(to_list("00000"))

print(op_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

with open('draft.txt', 'r') as src:
    lines = src.read().splitlines()
    row_count, col_count = lines[0].split(' ')

    m = np.zeros((int(row_count), int(col_count)))

    for i in range(1, len(lines)):
        m[i-1, :] = list(lines[i])

print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `input.txt` file is located in the same directory as your `.py` file and contains the following:

```
4 5
11110
11010
11000
00000
```

you can use the following to get your matrix as a list of lists:

```
with open('./input.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

    header = lines[0]
    num_rows, num_cols = (int(x) for x in header.split(' '))
    print(num_rows, num_cols)

    matrix = []
    for i in range(1, len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        line = line.rstrip() # get rid of '\n'
        as_nums = [int(num) for num in line]
        assert len(as_nums) == num_cols
        matrix.append(as_nums)

    assert len(matrix) == num_rows
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might help:

```py
inp = input()
rows, columns = map(int, inp.split())

lines = []
for i in range(rows):
  line = input()[:columns]
  lines.append([int(l) for l in line])

print(lines)
```

Input:

```
4 5
11110
11010
11000
00000
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```